# Is it possible to get the hardware details of a given sensor in iOS like android?

Tags: ios, sensors, cmmotionmanager

Hello All,

I am creating an iOS application which uses the accelerometer sensor. I am able to get the sensor data using `CMMotionManager`. I also want to get the sensor's hardware details like Sensor Name, Vendor, Type, Range, etc. I can get these values in Android, but I couldn't find a way to do it even after searching all over the internet. Is this possible to get those values in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get that information from iOS, mostly because there is only one vendor for iOS devices and that is Apple. On Android you can have many device providers and it makes sense to let you know more about that device tech specs, but not on iOS.

Comment: So sad :-(  Thank you @sebacancinos